# Can anyone explain why and how flames shot out of an F/A-18 as it crashed?

Tags: military, engine

Can anyone explain why and how flames have shot out of the left engine of this F/A-18, whose left engine was apparently not generating power, the picture is [here](https://forums.eagle.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=75479&d=1357241068). And the source website where I got the infomation from is [here](https://forums.eagle.ru/showthread.php?t=99807).
The accident happened in Lethbridge, Canada in the July of 2010. Below is a comment posted on the forum in response to the post of the crash on ED forums:

> It was a fuel control problem (sticky piston) on the right engine, isn't #1 the left? The open nozzle of the left engine indicates that it's either a) at idle or b) at full power/burner which it was in this case as the pilot was executing a high alpha pass at the time.

The comment about the left engine not hasving power is here:

> The left engine has the nozzle fully open, showing that #1 engine was developing no power.

Comment: Looks like the right engine to me.

Comment: @GregTaylor it is the left, it crashed with its canopy/cockpit facing the camera

Comment: It looks like [this incident](https://beta.theglobeandmail.com/news/national/investigation-finds-stuck-piston-likely-led-to-crash-of-cf-18-hornet-in-air-show-practice/article6220481/?ref=http://www.theglobeandmail.com&) involving a Canadian CF-18, considering the angle of the picture and the runway signs. There is also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HDIxzSMp-0) of the crash. Apparently the right engine was out of fuel and the Pilot was applying afterburner. Could be a leak of fuel that was ignited upon impact. Other users might know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuel has to reach the engine to make it work, so there is a path (pipes) available for the fuel to get from the tanks into the engines.

Looking (*) at the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HDIxzSMp-0) linked by [Pierre Chevallier](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44198/can-anyone-explain-why-and-how-flames-shot-out-of-an-f-a-18-as-it-crashed#comment113928_44198) it looks like some fuel got pressed out of the tanks, into the engine(s) and out the engine nozzle, and in the process it got ignited.

I cannot say why the fuel got only in one engine, I can guess that the valves on the fuel lines were in different positions.

(*) I suggest using the option to visualize at x0.25 speed, starting at the 0:30 mark

Comment: From the [report](http://www.rcaf-arc.forces.gc.ca/en/flight-safety/article-template-flight-safety.page?doc=cf188738-hornet-epilogue-flight-safety-investigation-report/hl7pe978): `The engine malfunction was likely the result of a stuck ratio boost piston in the right engine main fuel control (MFC) `. It seems your guess is right.